# How to properly format data to use in a pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, vulnerabilities

I am trying to format some data that I have into a pivot table, but I am having trouble understanding how I need to format both the original data and the pivot table to get the results that I want.

I have a list of assets with their name, categorizations they fall under, a description, and vulnerabilities that are applicable to them. You can see the headers of my data

[image]

This is an example of an asset entry in the table:

[image: here]

It's very basic and should be easy to convert to a pivot table.

Unfortunately, when I move the data to a pivot table not all assets are listed under each category as they are considered a separate category (because it is associated with 2 categories).

As seen:

[image: here]

the category *Bus* is missing 2 assets that are also associated with *Fare Collection*

I want to try and get the pivot table to look like:

[image: this]

So that I do not have to manipulate the raw data. Does anyone have any ideas on how I should change my approach to this?

Comment: So in you hand written example should ventra app be listed three times? Once under bus, again under fare collection and again under 3rd party?

Comment: @Mobus Yes, if the asset is in three categories I would like it to appear in all three in the pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

I stand to be corrected but I think pivot rows are like a normal table rows and won't duplicate data on its own (totals wont add up according to the original data). Also not sure if you can build the tree structure like you want. Pivot "rows"  input box will automatically cascade if you were to put category 1 with category 2 below it. I think you can put cascading/trees off altogether but that wont work for names and desc then. It also won't merge category 1, 2 and 3 (so "bus" in 1, 2 and 3 are considered different entities - I think).

Perhaps this could work... Maybe. Make a column for each category. Then put a  formula like this in each starting in P2 (assuming row1 is header, C D E are category 1-3  columns and the new category columns start in P):

```
=OR(P$2=$C2,P$2=$D2,P$2=$E2)
```

Now see if you can put all the categories in rows of a pivot table.

This will deal with the merge issue but not the duplication of the assets.  Perhaps the only way out here is to make seperate pivots for each category. Put a category column in the filter section. Then copy and paste the whole pivot to a new pivot below it. Change filter section to a different category. Repeat.

Comment: I don't have my pc with me to check but can a pivot "filter" apply a text search like a normal excel filter? If so you could also make a combined categories column `=C2&","&D2&","&E2` then use that as filter in the pivot to seach for all rows containing say "bus". Then duplicate that pivot table into multiple pivots and just change the filter for each.